# pivot_longer with multiple classes causes error ("No common type")

Tags: r, tidyr

I am running `pivot_longer` on multiple columns (i.e. two character columns and one numeric). I am encountering an error related to the class mismatch.

I have investigated the documentation for any "force" options and did not see any arguments within `pivot_longer` to specify the class to use -- or to allow the function auto-detect the most general class.

Are there any parameters within `pivot_longer` to avoid this error? Or do you need to convert the columns to a single class before running `pivot_longer`?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2) # Just for `diamonds` dataset

small_diamonds <- diamonds %>% 
  # Select a few columns (two character, one numeric, specifically integers)
  select(cut, color, price) %>% 
  # Create a row_id
  mutate(row_num = row_number()) 

# This works with `gather`
small_diamonds %>% 
  gather(key, val, - row_num)

# This fails due to class error:
small_diamonds %>% 
  # Pivot data
  pivot_longer( - row_num, 
                names_to = "key",
                values_to = "val")

# Output
# Error: No common type for `cut` <ordered<4bd7e>> and `price` <integer>.
# Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

# Convert columns to a single class (character) and then use `pivot_longer`. 
# Runs successfully
small_diamonds %>% 
  mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
  # Pivot data
  pivot_longer( - row_num, 
                names_to = "key",
                values_to = "val")
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We can specify the `values_ptype` in this case (as the value columns differ in types)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
small_diamonds %>%  
   pivot_longer( - row_num, 
             names_to = "key",
             values_to = "val", values_ptypes = list(val = 'character'))
# A tibble: 161,820 x 3
#   row_num key   val    
#     <int> <chr> <chr>  
# 1       1 cut   Ideal  
# 2       1 color E      
# 3       1 price 326    
# 4       2 cut   Premium
# 5       2 color E      
# 6       2 price 326    
# 7       3 cut   Good   
# 8       3 color E      
# 9       3 price 327    
#10       4 cut   Premium
# … with 161,810 more rows
```

Answer (score 30):

The error is now there again in a different guise when the `values_ptypes` argument is used.

```r
library(tidyverse)

small_diamonds <- diamonds %>% 
  select(cut, color, price) %>% 
  mutate(row_num = row_number())

small_diamonds %>%  
  pivot_longer( - row_num, 
                names_to = "key",
                values_to = "val", 
                values_ptypes = list(val = 'character'))
#> Error: Can't convert <integer> to <character>.
```

Therefore I need to use the `values_transform` argument to get the desired result.

```r
library(tidyverse)

  small_diamonds <- diamonds %>% 
    select(cut, color, price) %>% 
    mutate(row_num = row_number())
  
  small_diamonds %>%  
    pivot_longer( - row_num, 
                  names_to = "key",
                  values_to = "val", 
                  values_transform = list(val = as.character))
#> # A tibble: 161,820 x 3
#>    row_num key   val    
#>      <int> <chr> <chr>  
#>  1       1 cut   Ideal  
#>  2       1 color E      
#>  3       1 price 326    
#>  4       2 cut   Premium
#>  5       2 color E      
#>  6       2 price 326    
#>  7       3 cut   Good   
#>  8       3 color E      
#>  9       3 price 327    
#> 10       4 cut   Premium
#> # ... with 161,810 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I think the reason for this error is that the tidyverse crew wants a data type transformation to be explicit during pivoting.

Comment: Why this does not work with the relig_income dataset? relig_income %>% 
  pivot_longer(1:11, names_to = "a", 
               values_to = "b", 
               values_transform = list(val = as.character))

Comment: @DarioLacan It works when you specify the value column name correctly. In your code the column name for the value column is specified as `val`, but your value column is named as `b`, when I replace `val` with `b` the transformation works on my machine.

Answer (score 8):

Using your example, you can see with str() that you have two vectors encoded as factors, and two as integers. pivot_longer demands that all vectors are of the same type, and throws the error you have reported.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    small_diamonds <- diamonds %>%
      select(cut, color, price) %>%
      mutate(row_num = row_number())

    str(small_diamonds)
```

One solution is to convert all vector to characters with mutate.if, and then pass the pivot_longer command.

```
    small_diamonds %>% 
      mutate_if(is.numeric,as.character, is.factor, as.character) %>% 
      pivot_longer( - row_num, 
            names_to = "key",
            values_to = "val")
```

Comment: I believe that converting the columns before running pivot_longer produces a cleaner and more undestandable code. It is very obvious you are performing a conversion when you use the command "mutate". It also adheres to the Unix "kiss" principle: use one tool to convert data, and other to "pivot" the data.